# jquery.getScript does not execute callback when loading facebook sdk on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to execute some page initialization code after the facebook sdk file loads. Currently it silently fails and I am having a hard time debugging.

This happens only on firefox

```js
$.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js',    function () {
    debugger;
  // debugger is never hit, or if I add any console.logs
});
```

Comment: _“This happens only on firefox”_ – check your settings/extensions, it might have to do with privacy mode. Also check console to see if it says anything about it being blocked in there.

Comment: Thank you this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the full path of the script .You can use `.done` & `.fail` to account for any error

```
$.getScript( "http://somedomain/en_US/all.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    // Log the error
});
```

Comment: It already is “full” - URLs starting with `//` are called protocol-relative. It is a full address, the browser just prefixes it with the protocol the current parent page was requested with. (Useful for when your site is accessible via both HTTP and HTTPS.)

Comment: The issue had to do with the privacy settings on firefox. Thanks guys for your input.